# Pandas: Subtract Groupwise Minimum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `date` and from this I want to subtract the groupwise (grouped by `PID`) minimum of the `date`.

So I've calculated the groupwise minimum like this:
`df.groupby(by="PID").min()`

And wanted to subtract it where I'm stucked:
`df['date'] = df['date'] - ???`

What's the next step here? Or are there any methods that are easier?

My data looks somehow like this:

```
----------------------------
|   PID   |  DATE          |
----------------------------
|    5    |  2017-05-05    |
|    7    |  2016-10-04    |
|    7    |  2017-05-03    |
|    5    |  2016-12-20    |
|    5    |  2017-02-01    |
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer this with some example of your data (like the 5 first rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), which return `Series` with same index as `df`, so is possible subtract column:

```
print (df.groupby(by="PID")['DATE'].transform('min'))
0   2016-12-20
1   2016-10-04
2   2016-10-04
3   2016-12-20
4   2016-12-20
Name: DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df['new'] = df['DATE'] - df.groupby(by="PID")['DATE'].transform('min')
print (df)
   PID       DATE      new
0    5 2017-05-05 136 days
1    7 2016-10-04   0 days
2    7 2017-05-03 211 days
3    5 2016-12-20   0 days
4    5 2017-02-01  43 days
```